# How do I make this into a function?

Tags: r, function

I'm working with throughput data at a university. For each student, I need to calculate the percentage of achieved academic credits in relation to how many credits that student "should" have achieved given the current term on his or her programme.

Since my university lacks historical data I will need to do this by creating a reference table. I use a numerical vector of academic credits (representing the structure of the programme) and the unique start dates for that programme (representing the start date for "the year of 2001", "the yeae of 2002" and so forth).

From this I calculate the values start_date_point and end_date_point for different points in the programme. If Sys.date falls between start_date_points and end_date_points for that year and programme, then the expected amount of academic credits is the amount on that row.

For the Economics programme, I use the following code:

```
#Extracting unique start dates from fulldata, containing information for each student

    sd<-fulldata%>%dplyr::select(UTBILDNINGSTILLFALLE_STARTDATUM)%>%drop_na()%>%unique()
    sd<-sd$UTBILDNINGSTILLFALLE_STARTDATUM

    #Creating vector with structure of programme

    points_ekon<-c(15,15,15,15,7.5,7.5,15,7.5,7.5,15,15,15,30,0)

    #taking summer breaks into account

    summer_break_ekon<-c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)

    ekon_program<-cbind(points_ekon,summer_break_ekon)
    ekon_program<-as.data.frame(ekon_program)

    #One academic credit equals 1,5 weeks in my country

    ekon_program<-ekon_program%>%mutate(weeks_course=points_ekon/1.5)
    ekon_program<-ekon_program%>%mutate(points_expected=lag(cumsum(points_ekon)))
    ekon_program<-ekon_program%>%mutate(points_expected=ifelse(is.na(points_expected),0,points_expected))
    ekon_program<-ekon_program%>%mutate(order=1:n())
    ekon_program<-crossing(sd, ekon_program)
    ekon_program<-ekon_program%>%arrange(sd, order)

    ekon_program<-ekon_program%>%mutate(starttermin=ifelse(order==1,1,0))
    ekon_program$kull<-cumsum(ekon_program$starttermin)


    #We set start_date to sd-1 since we want to include the first day of school in our calculations

    ekon_program<-ekon_program%>%mutate(start_date=sd-1)
    ekon_program<-ekon_program%>%group_by(kull)%>%mutate(start_date_points=start_date+lag(cumsum(weeks_course)*7+3*7+summer_break_ekon*12*7))
    ekon_program<-ekon_program%>%group_by(kull)%>%mutate(end_date_points=start_date+cumsum(weeks_course)*7+3*7+summer_break_ekon*12*7-1)
    ekon_program<-ekon_program%>%mutate(start_date_points=if_else(is.na(start_date_points),start_date,as.Date(start_date_points)))
    ekon_program<-ekon_program%>%group_by(start_date)%>%mutate(finished_date=max(start_date_points))
    ekon_program<-ekon_program%>%mutate(finished=ifelse(lead(kull, default=0)==kull,0,1))

    #Joining with student data, calculating the expected credits for each year

    fulldata<-ekon_program%>%
    filter((Sys.Date()>finished_date & finished==1)|(Sys.Date()>=start_date_points & Sys.Date()<=end_date_points))%>%
    dplyr::select(sd,points_expected)%>%
    full_join(fulldata, by=c("sd"="UTBILDNINGSTILLFALLE_STARTDATUM"))
```

And get the following output (the reference table, not the student data):

```
    sd          points_ekon summer_break_ekon weeks_course points_expected order starttermin kull start_date start_date_points end_date_points finished_date finished    
    2016-08-29  7.5         1                 5             97.5            9     0          5      2016-08-28  2018-03-11     2018-04-14      2019-06-23   0
    2016-08-29  15.0        1                10            105.0           10     0          5      2016-08-28  2018-04-15     2018-06-23      2019-06-23   0
    2016-08-29  15.0        2                10            120.0           11     0          5      2016-08-28  2018-06-24     2018-11-24      2019-06-23   0
    2016-08-29  15.0        2                10            135.0           12     0          5      2016-08-28  2018-11-25     2019-02-02      2019-06-23   0
    2016-08-29  30.0        2                20            150.0           13     0          5      2016-08-28  2019-02-03     2019-06-22      2019-06-23   0
    2016-08-29  0.0         2                 0            180.0           14     0          5      2016-08-28  2019-06-23     2019-06-22      2019-06-23   1
    2017-08-28  15.0        0                10              0.0            1     1          6      2017-08-27  2017-08-27     2017-11-25      2020-06-21   0
    2017-08-28  15.0        0                10              15.0           2     0          6      2017-08-27  2017-11-26     2018-02-03      2020-06-21   0
    2017-08-28  15.0        0                10              30.0           3     0          6      2017-08-27  2018-02-04     2018-04-14      2020-06-21   0
    2017-08-28  15.0        0                10              45.0           4     0          6      2017-08-27  2018-04-15     2018-06-23      2020-06-21   0
    2017-08-28  7.5         1                 5              60.0           5     0          6      2017-08-27  2018-06-24     2018-10-20      2020-06-21   0
    2017-08-28  7.5         1                 5              67.5           6     0          6      2017-08-27  2018-10-21     2018-11-24      2020-06-21   0
    2017-08-28  15.0        1                10              75.0           7     0          6      2017-08-27  2018-11-25     2019-02-02      2020-06-21   0
    2017-08-28  7.5         1                 5              90.0           8     0          6      2017-08-27  2019-02-03     2019-03-09      2020-06-21   0
    2017-08-28  7.5         1                 5              97.5           9     0          6      2017-08-27  2019-03-10     2019-04-13      2020-06-21   0
    2017-08-28  15.0        1                10             105.0          10     0          6      2017-08-27  2019-04-14     2019-06-22      2020-06-21   0
    2017-08-28  15.0        2                10             120.0          11     0          6      2017-08-27  2019-06-23     2019-11-23      2020-06-21   0
    2017-08-28  15.0        2                10             135.0          12     0          6      2017-08-27  2019-11-24     2020-02-01      2020-06-21   0
    2017-08-28  30.0        2                20             150.0          13     0          6      2017-08-27  2020-02-02     2020-06-20      2020-06-21   0
    2017-08-28  0.0         2                 0             180.0          14     0          6      2017-08-27  2020-06-21     2020-06-20      2020-06-21   1
    2018-09-03  15.0        0                10               0.0           1     1          7      2018-09-02  2018-09-02     2018-12-01      2021-06-27   0
```

....So for instance, an Economics student from the year of 2017 (start date 2017-08-27) would be expected to have 135 credits given today's date.

That's all well and good, but i need to generalize this to several different programmes, so I need to make my code into a function.

I've tried the following, which should fetch the start dates for the programme from fulldata, provided I name the credits vectors the same as the programmes in fulldata:

```
start_dates<-function(x){
sd<-fulldata%>%
    filter(program == as.character(rlang::enexpr(x))) %>%
    distinct(UTBILDNINGSTILLFALLE_STARTDATUM)%>%drop_na()
sd<-sd$UTBILDNINGSTILLFALLE_STARTDATUM
}
sdEkonom<-start_dates(Ekonom)
sdMakekonom<-start_dates(Maklarekonom)
sdDititalamedier<-start_dates(Digitala_Medier)
```

Then I try to use these values in a second function (with the first part of the code only):

```
reference_table<-function(x,y){
summer_break<-ifelse(cumsum(x)<=60, 0, ifelse(cumsum(x)>60 & cumsum(x)<=120 , 1,2))
program<-cbind(x,summer_break)
program<-as.data.frame(program)
program<-program%>%rename(points=x)
program<-program%>%mutate(weeks_course=points/1.5)
program<-program%>%mutate(points_expected=lag(cumsum(points)))
program<-program%>%mutate(points_expected=ifelse(is.na(points_expected),0,points_expected))
program<-program%>%mutate(order=1:n())
program<-crossing(y, program)
program<-program%>%arrange(sd, order)
}
```

I type:

```
reference_table(Ekonom,sdEkonom)
```

And the script goes haywire, claiming either "incorrect size (8) at position 1, expecting : 112" or that my first argument is a data frame, which it obviously isn't.

What am I doing wrong and how can I make this work?

Input data:

Vector of academic credits:

```
Ekonom<-c(15,15,15,15,7.5,7.5,15,7.5,7.5,15,15,15,30,0)
```

Excerpt of start unique values in fulldata:

```
structure(list(UTBILDNINGSTILLFALLE_STARTDATUM = structure(c(15586, 
15586, NA, NA, 15950, 15950, 16314, 16314, 16678, 16678, NA, 
16678, 16678, 17042, 17042, 17042, 17042, 17406, 17406, 17406, 
17406, 17777, 17777, 17777, 18141, 18141, 18141), class = "Date"), 
    program = c("Ekonom", "Maklarekonom", "Maklarekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Maklarekonom", "Maklarekonom", "Ekonom", "Maklarekonom", 
    "Digitala_Medier", "Digitala_Medier", "Ekonom", "Ekonomi COOP", 
    "Maklarekonom", "Ekonom", "Digitala_Medier", "Ekonomi COOP", 
    "Ekonom", "Digitala_Medier", "Maklarekonom", "Ekonomi COOP", 
    "Maklarekonom", "Ekonom", "Digitala_Medier", "Maklarekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Digitala_Medier")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -27L))
```

Comment: I get an error when I run `sdEkonom<-start_dates(Ekonom)` on the data excerpt you posted. So you should probably sort that out before trying to generalize the code. As for generalizing it, I would recommend picking values of the variables you want to pass to your function, then running through it step by step to see where those error messages are coming from and focusing on fixing there.

Comment: hi, just a small tip for your code: you can put several ```%>%``` in a row to avoid rewriting the name of your dataset (see [here](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/pipe.html)) and you can create several variables in a unique ```mutate``` function so no need to rewrite ```mutate``` each time (see [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html))

Comment: @ulfelder

I updated the first row in the start_dates function to "sd<-fulldata%>%", I think that should to the trick.

Comment: Same error though: "incorrect size (8) at position 1, expecting : 112 "